# Can I enable javascript directly from my site?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if it is possible with the help of a button for example, to allow the user to enable javascript or disable it (but only enable it interests me) directly from our site.
That is to say, I have a website that needs javascript for animations or whatever and I would like everyone to be able to access it.
So make available to people a button to enable javascript if it is disabled.
Do you know what I'm talking about?

**Is this possible? Or am I dreaming?**

**And if so, do you have any leads?**

Comment: Instead of enabling/disabling JS, why not just enable/disable functionality on your site?  If a flag is set, do something.  If not, then don't do that thing?  I know I would certainly not like websites to be able to change my browser's configuration.

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: In general, the answer to "can I change the user's browser preferences / settings from within a website" is going to be "no".

Comment: You're dreaming :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, but the best you can do is add a `<noscript>` tag with a message specifically for people without JS enabled.  A huge majority of people keep JS enabled and never change this preference though.

Example:

```
<noscript>
  <h1>Please enable JavaScript in your browser for the best possible experience.</h1>
</noscript>
```